Nginx proxy pass for alias domain - Keep users in the alias
I am running a micro site within a main site by an alias domain that contents with specific prefix are assigned to the alias.
There are a number of internal links (like posts, products), all of which are pointing the main site, even if the browser's url is from the alias.
Say, I am surfing around abc.example.com, but all links in the page are to example.com.
Thus, even though a user comes to the website via the alias, after a single click, the user is directed to the main site.
Though I'd like to keep that feature for some contents, for other cases, I wonder if it is possible to keep them in the alias.
Below is a fraction of my current Nginx server block for the alias domain.
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name aliasURL;

    location /example {
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1/example/;
    proxy_set_header Host mainURL;
  }
}

I have tried with rewrite, but then it does not keep the original URL, I suppose. Handling SSL was another issue. Alternatively, I also have done some studies on cookies that once a user got hooked to the alias domain's cookie, the user stays in that alias, but not sure if it works for this case.

Ensure that requests for specific paths or types of content remain on the alias domain.
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name abc.example.com;

    # SSL configuration
    ssl_certificate /path/to/ssl_certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/ssl_certificate_key.key;

    # Proxy requests for specific paths
    location /example {
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1/example/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    # Redirect other requests to maintain the alias
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

Furthermore, if your internal links are hardcoded and pointing to the main url, you might have to rewrite the urls in Nginx using sub_filter from example.com to abc.example.com

Host $host -> 414 error

Other than the 'Host', I already have an identical setting, but it does not work. Guess I need sub_filter options
